# Rails 5 ActionCable modify confirm_subscription

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, actioncable

I got this channel:

```
class TestChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def subscribed
    stream_from 'test'

    ActionCable.server.broadcast 'Test', vehicles: Vehice.find_by id: 13
  end
end
```

I don't wanna broadcast to all subscriber when someone subscribe.
I was thinking about changing `confirm_subscription` with adding `'message'`.

Can someone tell me if it's even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [transmit](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionCable/Channel/Base.html#method-i-transmit) to send a message only to the current subscription. It's not really documented and somehow an anti pattern (because in a pub sub scenario, each message in a channel should reach every user), but it works fine. We use it for "responding" with error messages when the client sends an invalid request.